# count how many times a row from a query appear on all the table

Tags: php, mysql, count, subquery

I have this query it's work fine

```
  $con    = "SELECT     id, fecha, id_px FROM mytable WHERE date='$fe' AND id_nut='$id' AND id_suc = '$su' AND confirm != '3'
```

but i need know how many times appear each `id_px` resultant from this query on the table regardless the date and whith other criteria

something like this query

```
 SELECT id_px, paciente, id FROM consultas2 WHERE id_px='$id_px' AND cobrado=1 LIMIT 22
```

the final result i need is all the data from the first query like this

```
$consultas = array(
    'id'     => $tim['id'],
    'id_nutr' => $tim['id_nut'],
    'date'    => $tim['date'],

        --this is the data i need--> 

    'total_cns' =>$tim['?']

        --the total of num rows of the second query--
);
```

how can achieve that?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: yes, thanks in advance! i hope the new block of code can help!

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the total count of results that match $id_px

```
SELECT count(*) FROM consultas2 WHERE id_px='$id_px' AND cobrado=1
```